# FP: What does "order" mean in "high order" functions? Does recursive function a "high order" function?

Tags: recursion, functional-programming

I have doubt about what's the real meaning of "order" when we say "high order" functions? E.g., I've got an embedded function call like:

```
f.g.h
```

So is it called a "3 order" function?

Is "High order" function a concept of static function accumulation? Then when I have a recursive function f, and in runtime its calling stack is like f.f.f.f. can we say f is high order function?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The order is basically the nesting level of arrows in the type.

[This lecture slide on *Functional Programming*](http://people.cs.aau.dk/~normark/prog3-03/html/notes/higher-order-fu_themes-intr-section.html#higher-order-fu_definition_title_1) defines

> The order of data
>
> - Order 0: Non function data
> - Order 1: Functions with domain and range of order 0
> - Order 2: Functions with domain and range of order 1
> - Order k: Functions with domain and range of order k-1

So basically a zeroth-order function is no function, a first-order normal function that only operates on data, and everything else is a higher-order function.

([These slides](https://cs.nyu.edu/courses/summer02/G22.2110-001/lect4.pdf) seem to have an off-by-one error)

Let's get to some (Haskell) examples:

```
-- no arrow, clearly some plain data
x :: Int
x = 0

-- one arrow, so it's a first-order function:
add2 :: Int -> Int
add2 = (+ 2)

-- still one arrow only:
add :: (Int, Int) -> Int
add = uncurry (+)

-- and this is a first-order function as well:
add4 :: Int -> Int
add4 = add2 . add2
```

As you can see, it doesn't matter whether you are using function composition (a higher-order function) to define your functions, only their result type matters. Therefore your `f.g.h` and `f.f.f.f` examples are only first-order functions (given that `f` is one).

Simple examples of higher-order functions are multivariate functions:

```
-- two arrows! Looks like a second-order function
plus :: Int -> Int -> Int
plus = (+)
```

The type of the curried function is actually `Int -> (Int -> Int)` where we can clearly see that it's a function that has a first-order function as the result, so it is of order 2. The lower order of the input (0) doesn't really matter.

We can see the same in a more interesting example, function composition:

```
compose :: ((b -> c), (a -> b)) -> a -> c
compose (f, g) x = f (g x)
```

Here both of the parameters and the result are each a first-order function, so `compose` is of order 2.

Another example is the fixpoint combinator `fix :: (a -> a) -> a` which does have a first-order function as the input and a zeroth-order result, making it second order overall.

And the curried composition operator as we know it

```
(.) :: (b -> c) -> ((a -> b) -> (a -> c))
```

would even be considered a third-order function.

Comment: The origin of the term is likely derived from [higher order logics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic#Higher-order_logics) in mathematics.

Answer (score 1):

An example (javaish)

```
Function<Double, Double> oneOf(Function<Double, Double>... fs) {
     return fs[new Random().nextInt(fs.length)];
}

double y = oneOf(cos, sin, atan).applyTo(1.23);
```

This is order 2 for two reasons: parameter type and especially the result type are functions.

Comment: I would've counted that as order 2. Where did you learn that definition?